# how to get hyperlink value and text field using jquery

Tags: jquery

Structure of code is like this and it is in iframe.

```
<div id="abc">
<div id="bcd"><a href="i want this hyperlink" title="sdf"><img src="" alt="i want this text"</a>
<div><h1><a href="i want this hyperlink">i want this text</a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have tried like this but this is not working

```
var $links= $("#frametest").contents().find("#abc").contents().find("#bcd").contents().find('a');
var link= $links.attr['href'];
alert(link);
```

Comment: Is the iframe displaying a page from the same domain ?

Answer (score 1):

Just try with:

```
$('#bcd a').each(function(){
  var link = $(this).attr('href');
  var text = $(this).text();
  alert(text + ': ' + link);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

to find text:

```
$('#bcd').find('a').each(function(index){
     $(this).text();
});
```

to find href:

```
$('#bcd').find('a').each(function(index){
     $(this).attr('href');
});
```

together:

```
$('#bcd').find('a').each(function(index){
         alert($(this).attr('href') + ' ' + $(this).text());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var link = $('#bcd a').attr('href');
text=$('#bcd a').text();
alert(link+"----"+text);
```